# Groovy: How to sort String array of text+numbers by last digit

Tags: groovy

I have array like this:

```
    def arr = [ 
      "v3.1.20161004.0",
      "v3.1.20161004.1",
      "v3.1.20161004.10",
      "v3.1.20161004.11",
      "v3.1.20161004.2",
      "v3.1.20161004.3",
      "v3.1.20161004.30",
    ]
```

I need to get this:

```
    def arr = [ 
      "v3.1.20161004.0",
      "v3.1.20161004.1",
      "v3.1.20161004.2",
      "v3.1.20161004.3",
      "v3.1.20161004.10",
      "v3.1.20161004.11",
      "v3.1.20161004.30",
    ]
```

How to sort it by last number '.x' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tokenize each string on `.` and then grab the last element as an Integer, and sort on this (passing `false` to return a new list)

```
def newArray = arr.sort(false) { it.tokenize('.')[-1] as Integer }
```

Comment: Thank You! This is gorgeous solution!

Answer (score 2):

When sorting an array you can define a sorting closure. In this case you can split on the dot and sort using the spaceship operator:

```
arr.sort { a, b -> a.tokenize('.').last().toInteger() <=> b.tokenize('.').last().toInteger() }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, it is usefull for me.