# Groovy: How to sort array of text and numbers by numbers in middle

Tags: groovy

I have an array like this:

```
def array = [ 
  "release-3.0.0-1-a6gbd6",
  "release-3.0.0-10-h7bdbc",
  "release-3.0.0-12-7hbs6",
  "release-3.0.0-23-9sz6gd",
  "release-3.0.0-3-g6h8xd",
]
```

I need it to be able to sort it by numbers in the middle (e.g. 3.0.0-1) in reverse order to look like this:

```
def array = [ 
  "release-3.0.0-23-9sz6gd",
  "release-3.0.0-12-7hbs6",
  "release-3.0.0-10-h7bdbc",
  "release-3.0.0-3-g6h8xd",
  "release-3.0.0-1-a6gbd6",
]
```

How can I do this with Groovy?

I tried following [Groovy: How to sort String array of text+numbers by last digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855518/groovy-how-to-sort-string-array-of-textnumbers-by-last-digit) but am not having any luck

Comment: Does the answer here work?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7737400/6509

Comment: Sort of. I'll keep looking for more examples. Thanks

Comment: What's that one missing? What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be working

```
def newArray = array.sort(false){[it.tokenize('-')[-3], it.tokenize('-')[-2] as Integer]}
```

Here we are sorting on the string after the first dash, and then sorting by the integer after the second dash